# Question regarding domain of trignometric function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The question is as follows

Find the domain of the function
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + 2 \sin(x)}$$

since $\sin(x) \neq \frac{-1}{2}$ therefore the general expression for this should be as follows

$$x \neq n\pi + (-1)^{n-1}\frac{\pi}{6}$$

This equation i derived my self and seems about right however the answer given in the textbook is the following

$$x \neq n\pi + (-1)^n \frac{7\pi}{6}$$

Are the above two equations exactly the same or am i wrong?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check for $n=0$. Which one is right?

Comment: @Peter seems about right yields to negative $\frac{\pi}{6}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are exactly the same, yes. Generate a list of values from each:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
n & s_1(n) = n\pi + (-1)^{n-1}\frac{\pi}{6} & s_2(n) = n\pi + (-1)^n \frac{7\pi}{6} \\ \hline
0 & - \frac \pi 6  & \color{red}{\frac{7\pi}{6}} \\ 
1 & \pi + \frac \pi 6 = \color{red}{\frac{7\pi}{6}} & \pi-\frac{7\pi}{6} = -\frac{\pi}{6}\\ 
2 & 2\pi - \frac \pi 6 = \color{blue}{\frac{11\pi}{6}} & 2\pi+\frac{7\pi}{6} = \color{green}{\frac{19\pi}{6}} \\ 
3 & 3\pi + \frac \pi 6 = \color{green}{\frac{19\pi}{6}}& 3\pi-\frac{7\pi}{6}  = \color{blue}{\frac{11\pi}{6}}\\ 
4 & 4 \pi - \frac \pi 6= \color{purple}{\frac{23\pi}{6}} & 4\pi+\frac{7\pi}{6} = \color{orange}{\frac{31\pi}{6}} \\ 
5 & 5 \pi + \frac \pi 6 = \color{orange}{\frac{31\pi}{6}}& 5\pi-\frac{7\pi}{6}  = \color{purple}{\frac{23\pi}{6}}\\ 
\end{array}$$

This pattern continues: each list enumerates the same numbers, but in a slightly twisted order. Namely, if $n$ is even, then $s_1(n) = s_2(n+1)$ and $s_1(n+1) = s_2(n)$. This equality that is hinted at allows us to prove this in general:
$$
s_1(n) = s_2(n+1)
\iff
n\pi + (-1)^{n-1}\frac{\pi}{6} = (n+1)\pi + (-1)^{n+1} \frac{7\pi}{6}
$$
However, note that $(-1)^{n \pm 1} = -1$ since $n$ is even, and that  $\frac{7\pi}{6} = \frac \pi 6 + \pi$. Then
$$
(n+1)\pi + (-1)^{n+1} \frac{7\pi}{6}
= n\pi - \frac{\pi}{6} + \pi - \pi
= n\pi - \frac{\pi}{6} = s_1(n)
$$
as desired. Similar for the other equality.